# how to get last inserted primary key

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, dropzone.js

Drag & Drop file upload handle by [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). When file uploaded into db i will get the response `insert 'Id'`. I want that id for further processing

In HTML i have multiple check box that user can select two or there files to processed next page.For this case i  need return id of the file upload.

```
#upload.html
<div class="tb-column col-5"><p class="name" data-dz-name></p></div>
<div class="tb-column col-2"><p class="size" data-dz-size></p></div>
<div class="sel"><input type="checkbox" value="???" id="check"></div>
```

In bottom of the page i tried to get the id using alert function but nothing happend

```
success: function(id)
{alert(id);}
```

Comment: is it coming in the success callback?

Comment: you want to alert the `insert 'Id'`?

Comment: @V31 no .. because if i put success in dropzonejs script inside, i can't able to upload file, so i can't check that.

Comment: If it is not coming in the success callback then you wont be able to alert the id

Comment: @HTTP I am sure i can get response id each time file upload happens. If i am getting the return id one by one and  assign the id into that check box.  i can able to work on my further implementation here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base from what I understand from your question and the comments your problem was to assign the returned `id` to the checkbox. Then use the `.attr`.

```
$('#your-checkbox-id').attr('id', //value of id here);
```

Then you can get the value by getting its `attr`.

```
var checkbox_id = $('#your-checkbox-id').attr('id');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't know how to ask that question, sorry for that. I am not sure id is the correct word here but i can get the response id in my ubuntu terminal.